# What should be in "pattern": of Artifactory downloadSpec file to search both folder and subfolder

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

What should be in  "pattern": of Artifactory downloadSpec file to include or skip sub folder

repo / folderA  / folderB  / *.xml

repo / folderA  /  *.xml

So I need to download xmls from folderA or from specific subfolder of folderA
Normally I would write :: "pattern": "repo/folderA/**/*.xml" but this pattern cant find artifacts under folderA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you have a small amount of folders under folderA, you can use the "excludePatterns" feature. For example:

```
{
"files": [
    {
        "pattern": "repo/folderA/*.xml",
        "excludePatterns": ["folderA/folderC/*","folderA/folderd/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more about exclude patterns on [JFrog CLI File Specs documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs) or [JFrog CI servers File Specs documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-DownloadSpecSchema) (use the one that relevant for you).
If you have too many folders under folderA or the folders name will be changed in future, use two fileSpacs for download:

```
{
"files": [
    {
        "pattern": "repo/folderA/*.xml",
        "recursive": false
    },
    {
        "pattern": "repo/folderA/folderB/*.xml",
        "recursive": false
    }
  ]
}
```